# CSS - How to fit div at the right side of a left sidebar and resize it on window resize

Tags: html, css, sidebar

I am trying to make content container in the middle beside the left bar but cant get it to resize properly on window resize and still have the whole content container not going outside of the view of the window.

https://jsfiddle.net/ptm7f6cL/

**The problem is if I remove the width:calc(100% - 200px); from the APP - div on resize it will loose part of the right side and it wont be visible.**
[image: Img3]

**This is ok if I use width:calc(100% - 200px);**

[image: Img1]

**But when I resize it there is this gap:**
How to remove the green gap and still have the container to resize properly without loosing the 200px on the right side.

[image: Img2]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="padding: 0; position:fixed; left: 0; margin: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: purple;">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body style="padding: 0; left: 0; margin: 0; top: 0;  width: 100%;  min-width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: lime;">

  <!--Wrapper-->
  <div style="  width: 100%; height: 100%; display: inline-flex;">

    <!--LEFTBAR-->
    <div style="max-width: 200px; min-width: 200px; width: inherit; box-sizing: border-box;  height: inherit; max-height:100%; padding: 10px; left:0; top: 0; background-color:green;">
      <h1>sadsdsadsad</h1>
    </div>



    <!--Wrapper 2-->
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;  ">

      <!--TOPBAR-->
      <div style="display: inline-flex; width: 100%; height: 50px; padding: 10px; right:0; bottom: 0; background-color: sandybrown;">
        <h1> adfgggggghhhhjjjjjjjjkkkkkkkllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll</h1>
        <h1> ad</h1>
        <h1> ad</h1>
        <h1> ad</h1>
        <h1> ad</h1>
        <h1> ad</h1>
      </div>


      <!--APP-->
      <div style=" width:calc(100% - 200px); max-width: 100%; height:calc(100% - 70px); box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; padding: 10px; right:0; bottom: 0; background-color:aqua;">
        <iframe style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; height:100%;" src="https://iconarchive.com/"></iframe>
      </div>

      <!-- Wrapper 3 Right Right -->
      <!-- <div style="float: right; height:calc(100% - 70px); background-color:red;"> -->


    </div>


    <!-- Wrapper-Right 3 -->
    <!-- <div style="position: relative; width:10px; height: 100%; background-color: orange;"></div> -->

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

**Without position: fixed; on the Html tag**

[image: Img4]

Regards

Comment: Your APP div has `width:calc(100% - 200px);` -> therefor you get 200px space on the right. Your concurent DIVs are LEFTBAR and Wrapper 2 -> check their sizes and positions.

Comment: The problem is if I remove the width:calc(100% - 200px); from the APP - div on resize it will loose part of the right side and it wont be visible.

Comment: Why do you have position: fixed on your HTML tag?

Comment: Why aren't you using classes?

Comment: I am not using classes because I am testing it know. The Position:fixed; on the html is because on resize it gets smaller than the screen. I am testing it with dev tools on chrome but for the mobile version.

Comment: Could you please move your CSS into CSS, and out of the HTML? This makes it much easier to help, it allows you to reuse classes, and trims down the size of the content you need to serve to each user on page-load. "*I am not using classes because I am testing it know.*" - you're making it harder for yourself by using inline CSS.

Comment: Is this ok - https://jsfiddle.net/ptm7f6cL/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the design that you're trying is totally the wrong way to go. What you need is to create a hamburger icon that slides the `.left-bar`, but otherwise keep it hidden. Given, I don't know what either the `.top-bar` or `.left-bar` is for.

You should make it a habit of always creating classes. I removed your comments, and named the divs by it's classes instead.

You should never have more than one `h1` tag on the page, because search engines use that to categorize your page.

I think the key point in this CSS is to add `overflow: hidden` to the `.top-bar` element, because it's children is messing up the whole structure of the page.

I'm not satisfied with the solution of calculating the height of the iframe (`.app`). Could probably achieve the same thing with some clever flex attributes instead.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: purple;
}

body {
  background-color: lime;
}

.wrapper-1 {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper-2 {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.top-bar {
  height: 50px;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: sandybrown;
}

.app,
.top-bar, 
.left-bar {
  padding: 10px;
}

.left-bar > h1,
.top-bar > h1
{
  margin: 0px;
}

.app {
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-1">
  <div class="left-bar">
    <h1>sadsdsadsad</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper-2">

    <div class="top-bar">
      <h1> adfgggggghhhhjjjjjjjjkkkkkkkllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll</h1>
      <h1> ad</h1>
      <h1> ad</h1>
      <h1> ad</h1>
      <h1> ad</h1>
      <h1> ad</h1>
    </div>

    <iframe class="app" src="https://iconarchive.com/"></iframe>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer: My Monitor is 2560x1080 and there was still green area at the right of the app iframe I added width: 100% to the wrapper div and now it works. The other problem was that the html element on resize with the dev tools mobile simulation was behaving strange and I added position: fixed; to the html again. I dont know if there is a better way of achieving that without using position: fixed; for the html tag. But it works now thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    style="padding: 0; position:fixed; left: 0; margin: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: purple;">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body
    style="padding: 0; left: 0; margin: 0; top: 0;  width: 100%;  min-width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: lime;">

    <!--Wrapper-->
    <div style="  width: 100%; height: 100%; display: inline-flex;">

        <!--LEFTBAR-->
        <div
            style="max-width: 200px; min-width: 200px; width: inherit; box-sizing: border-box;  height: inherit; max-height:100%; padding: 10px; left:0; top: 0; background-color:green;">
            <h1>sadsdsadsad</h1>
        </div>



        <!--Wrapper 2-->
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;  ">

            <!--TOPBAR-->
            <div
                style="display: inline-flex; width: 100%; height: 50px; padding: 10px; right:0; bottom: 0; background-color: sandybrown;">
                <h1> adfgggggghhhhjjjjjjjjkkkkkkkllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll</h1><h1> ad</h1><h1> ad</h1><h1> ad</h1><h1> ad</h1><h1> ad</h1>
            </div>


            <!--APP-->
            <div style="max-width: 100%; height:calc(100% - 70px); box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; padding: 10px; right:0; bottom: 0; background-color:aqua;">
                <iframe style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; height:100%;" src="https://iconarchive.com/"></iframe> 
            </div>
            
                    <!-- Wrapper 3 Right Right -->
                    <!-- <div style="float: right; height:calc(100% - 70px); background-color:red;"> -->
         
                     
        </div>


        <!-- Wrapper-Right 3 -->
        <!-- <div style="position: relative; width:10px; height: 100%; background-color: orange;"></div> -->

    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The problem is that on resize it will loose part of the right side.

Comment: "*[Try] this code*" -why? What have you changed, what have you improved? How?

Comment: He replaced width:calc(100% - 200px); with width:100%;

Comment: No. Just remove width property. Do you want to responsive this project?

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks to @Rickard Elimaa I got it working.**
I am still using position: fixed, for the html tag but I dont know otherwise how to do it so the html element does not get strange size on resize with the mobile simulation in the dev tools.

It seams that the part that fixed the problem was just adding `overflow: hidden;` to the wrapper 2.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: purple;
}

html{
  position: fixed;
}


body {
  background-color: lime;
}

.wrapper-1 {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper-2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.top-bar {
  height: 50px;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: sandybrown;
}


.left-bar {
  background-color: red;
  min-width: 50px;
  max-width: 200px;
}


.app,
.top-bar, 
.left-bar {
  padding: 10px;
}

.left-bar > h1,
.top-bar > h1
{
  margin: 0px;
}

.app {
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: aqua;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    

    <div class="wrapper-1">
        <div class="left-bar">
          <h1>sadsdsadsad</h1>
        </div>
      
        <div class="wrapper-2">
      
          <div class="top-bar">
            <h1> adfgggggghhhhjjjjjjjjkkkkkkkllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll</h1>
            <h1> ad</h1>
            <h1> ad</h1>
            <h1> ad</h1>
            <h1> ad</h1>
            <h1> ad</h1>
          </div>
      
          <iframe class="app" src="https://iconarchive.com/"></iframe>
          
        </div>
      </div>
      



</body>
</html>
```